# Accessibility (JAWS) - Dropdown list with Jquery Searchable-Multi-select-jQuery-Dropdown

Tags: accessibility, jaws-screen-reader

I am using searchable multiselect JQuery control [from here](https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Searchable-Multi-select-jQuery-Dropdown.html). [Demo control -- I am using Multi-select+JSON+Token Mode control](https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Searchable-Multi-select-jQuery-Dropdown/)

This is lightweight and useful plug in. I am using "Multi-select+JSON+Token Mode" model control, But I am facing issues with Accessibility issues with Screen reader JAWS. The problems are

1. Screen reader is not reading the selected option(Even though I added `ariaSelected: true` on option selection).
2. Without a screen reader, I can perfectly move across the different options (up-down keys). However, when JAWS is active, I can't perform this action. When hitting the down key, the options are not being selected although JAWS reads the next option (I can keep hitting the down key and JAWS will read the next option every time, but these are never selected - hitting Intro after a option is spoke is not selecting it either).

Can Someone help me to solve these issues.